How to draw Heaviside's step function with tkzFct?
For my homework I have to use the Heaviside sigma function I can draw the plain function in tkzFct with the definition
x>0 ? 1 : 0

but now I need to compose it with other functions, like σ(x^2-4). I know, how to define it in gnuplot, but where to insert it in tkzFct? (There is no working example yet...)

How automated do you need this to be?  For your example, I would plot 1 when |x|>2 and decide I'm done.

Could you please provide a few examples of what this function is supposed to do? Does it output 1 for positive inputs, and 0 for nonpositive inputs? My guess is that if this is the case, you'll need to manually find the domains and plot them individually. You could also use conditionals to do it, but that's more advanced. A picture of what you're looking for would go a long way in helping find an answer.

@Jasper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Thank you, that's what I suspected, but was also thinking that they could mean a sigmoid function. I'll see if I can't get this to work.

@ Jasper: For example I'd like to draw σ(x²-2). Ok, this is solvable with a few domains, but what about some heavily varying inner functions?

@ThomasBenko just alter the definition of f(\x) in my answer below to whatever function you want. As long as the domain fit within TeX's limits my answer should work.

@Jasper you should undelete your answer! It shows nice code. The fact that other answers reach similar results doesn't invalidate your solution (which has aspects OP seems to be after that mine doesn't have).

@Skillmon Thank you for your positive feedback, I've added it again, and have also elaborated on it to include a pgffor solution (as well as to include a preferred way of approaching these problem generally with algebra)

The following is a pretty straight forward pgfplots based solution. Note that with too few samples the points where f(x) == 0 turn out not nearly as sharp as they do in this example.
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x-4; H(\x)=\x<0?0:1;}]
  \begin{axis}[domain=-3:3, samples=501]
    \addplot[color=red] {f(x)};
    \addlegendentry{$x^2-4$}
    \addplot[color=blue] {H(f(x))};
    \addlegendentry{$\sigma(x^2-4)$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This is very good, looks pretty. The only problem is the vertical lines at the stepping, How to get rid of them?

@ThomasBenko that wasn't part of your original post (and many illustrations/plots of Heaviside's step function I know of feature those). If you don't want them and still want your function to be providable as an argument to it you'd need much more code for that to happen. Or you do the hard stuff by hand (knowing where the steps occur) and draw the function without \addplot but using \draw.

Sometimes I forgot the cultural differences. In Hungary we usually don't draw those vertical lines.

This is an answer in plain tikz to show how you could do the conditionals. The only problem is it can't plot the parts which are really close to the x-axis, unless you jack up the sample size.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\myFunction}[1]{(#1)^2-4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\myFunction{-5}}
\foreach \Vt in {-4.9,-4.8,...,5}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\Vt}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\myFunction{\Vt}}
% the function
\draw[red] (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
% the negative part
\ifdim\lasty pt<0pt
\ifdim\Vy pt<0pt
\draw[red] (\lastx,0) -- (\Vx,0);
\fi
\fi
% the positive part
\ifdim\lasty pt>0pt
\ifdim\Vy pt>0pt
\draw[red] (\lastx,1) -- (\Vx,1);
\fi
\fi
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy}
\global\let\lastx\lastx
\global\let\lasty\lasty
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As an elaboration, I did it in pgffor because of the simpler syntax. It produces the same output.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\myFunction}[1]{(#1)^2-4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastix{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastiy{\myFunction{-5}}
\foreach \Vt [
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vx using \Vt,%
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vy using {\myFunction{\Vt}},
    remember=\Vx as \lastx (initially \lastix),
    remember=\Vy as \lasty (initially \lastiy),
] in {-4.95,-4.9,...,5}{
\draw[red] (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
% the negative part
\ifdim\lasty pt<0pt
\ifdim\Vy pt<0pt
\draw[red] (\lastx,0) -- (\Vx,0);
\fi
\fi
% the positive part
\ifdim\lasty pt>0pt
\ifdim\Vy pt>0pt
\draw[red] (\lastx,1) -- (\Vx,1);
\fi
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Of course, imho, there is no substitute in such cases for finding the zeroes ourselves algebraically, and then plotting everything precisely: (for harder functions, you could even use a CAS). This gets rid of the need to jack up the samples.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\myFunction}[1]{(#1)^2-4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[red,samples=100,variable=\Vt,domain=-5:5] plot (\Vt,{\myFunction{\Vt}});
\draw[red,thick] (-5,1) -- (-2,1);
\draw[red,thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[red,thick] (2,1) -- (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As an elaboration, you could even use parse=true with a step of (3-(-3))/n
